# R - group by and summarise categorial vars (top 2 with count)

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, categorical-data, summarize

I Need to group a data.frame by field A and summarise categorical var B, keeping its top 2 values with respective counts. There are duplicate values for B.

Example data:

```
## double to have duplicate values
mtcars2 <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars)
```

Example wished code (although I know it's not simple like that):

```
mtcars2 %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    disp_top1 = top(disp,1),
    disp_top1_n = top_count(cat1,1),
    disp_top2 = top(disp,2),
    disp_top2_n = top_count(cat1,2)
  )
```

The result would by something like

```
   gear    nr disp_top1 disp_top1_n disp_top2 disp_top2_n
  <dbl> <int>     <dbl>       <int>     <dbl>       <int>
1     3    30      472            2       460           2
2     4    24      168.           4       160           4
3     5    10      351            2       301           2
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example as a code in your question.  What do you mean by top1 and top2?  Is top1 the mode and top2 the mode after removing the top1?

Comment: Thanks @Dharman and Holzben. Sorry for not posting reproducible code and testing data, newbie mistakes =). I edited the question, using mtcars.

I tried Dharman solution, didn't work for 2+ repeated values of disp, So I made some adaptations and now it's working. Code bellow.

Wonder if there's a shorter and faster way, since I need to summarise 200 categorical vars over 200 million records.

Comment: @AnilGoyal, thanks for the tip! Question edited. Also registered the solution I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no test data I can only provide a schematic example with the `mtcars` dataset

```
mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% 
  mutate(position = rank(disp)) %>% 
  summarise(nr = n(),
            top_value_1 = disp[position == 1],
            top_value_2 = disp[position == 2],
            top_value_3 = disp[position == 3],
            top_value_nr_occurance_top_1 = sum(disp[position == 1] == disp),
            top_value_nr_occurance_top_2 = sum(disp[position == 2] == disp),
            top_value_nr_occurance_top_3 = sum(disp[position == 3] == disp))
```

in your example `gear` would be `key` and `disp` would be `cat1`

Answer (score 0):

Answer so far (using mtcars as dataset), thanks to @holzben and @Dharman.

```
## double the data to get duplicate disp values
mtcars2 <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars)

## summarising
mtcars2 %>% group_by(gear) %>% 
  mutate(position = dense_rank(-disp)) %>% 
  summarise(
    nr = n(),
    top_value_1 = head(disp[position == 1],1),
    top_value_2 = head(disp[position == 2],1),
    top_value_1_nr = sum(top_value_1 == disp),
    top_value_2_nr = sum(top_value_2 == disp)
  )
```

result:

```
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
   gear    nr top_value_1 top_value_2 top_value_1_nr top_value_2_nr
  <dbl> <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>          <int>          <int>
1     3    30        472          460              2              2
2     4    24        168.         160              4              4
3     5    10        351          301              2              2
```